# Adding quick links to Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'd like to have quick links to my most frequently used sites right in my Gmail.

Is there a gadget which allows adding URL links to Gmail sidebar (I can only find gadgets with links to specific services rather than custom links)?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in the labs section of gmail for `quick links` by Dan P

> Adds a box to the left column that gives you 1-click access to any bookmarkable URL in Gmail. You can use it for saving frequent searches, important individual messages and more.

Labs is accessed via the cog in the top left of the gmail page

Comment: Quick Links allows only GMail URL while I was looking for the way to have a links to external sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Box of Links](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/117336448282898488901/mylinkbox.xml) gadget is the perfect solution for what I was looking for.